# Windows 11: Cannot open\copy a file

Tags: windows, pdf, windows-11

I have several pdf files in my windows users myuser folder which I fail to open or even copy to another folder.
Please review images for error messages.
Can you advise please? Please ask me for more details if required.

Trying to open the file:

[image: Trying to open the file]

Trying to copy the file:

[image: Trying to copy the file]

An ACL file example:

[image]

Please note that when I use the preview pane on the windows explorer, I can see the file preview at it whole! I can't tell what does that mean...

[image]

Comment: Move one or more of the files to c:\temp (make the folder) and see if it opens there. That will help let you know if the problem is OS or App

Comment: How positive are you that the files are actually there, and you are not dealing with ghost files that were deleted due to a larger issue? Can you view the properties of the file in question and provide the ACL for it as an edit to your question.

Comment: Run `chkdsk C:` (without the `/f` parameter) and let us know what it finds.

Comment: @John I can't copy or move the files. I get the error I posted.

Comment: @Ramhound uploaded. I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: @dushkin - If you copy the file, to another location, can you open file that is created in that new location? This should be a location outside of the user profile. If you cannot copy the file to a new location, then the file is likely orphaned, if you were to perform Check Disk the files likely would be deleted. I don't recognized either of those prompts.

Comment: @harrymc 
Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

Comment: Try to copy the files while booting in Safe mode.

Comment: cheat mode: get DMDE > run > logical drives > c: (assuming this is on c:) > click Open Volume > expand folder > see if files are there, if so 'recover' them. Up to 4000 files can be recovered per folder using free version.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen YES YES YES!!! Thank you so much. This DMDE is tha heck of a recovery app! You may answer the question and I'll gladly accept it. Thank you all guys for your effort and attention!

Comment: Nice, I'll post as answer then.

Comment: Can you try copying it from Command Prompt? Somehthing like `copy "C:\Users\<your name\Downloads\DSbooklet.pdf" "C:\Users\<your name\Desktop"`. I'm afraid it's actually the preview pane loading the file and blocking the copying

Comment: @dushkin - It's not normal that a file that like would be inaccessible.  You should seriously think about replacing the drive.  Just because check disk didn't detect any errors does not mean the disk isn't failing.  Inaccessible files, which you have permissions to, is the first sign of a disk problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheat mode, we'll bypass the file system:

Get [DMDE](https://dmde.com/) > run > logical disks > select the c: drive (assuming this is on c:) > click 'Open Volume' > expand folder > see if files are there, if so 'recover' them.

Up to 4000 files can be recovered per folder using free version, every session. If you need more, simply restart DMDE.